# Populate form from database model

Tags: django, django-admin

I have the following information about a person and a button, in the admin interface, to go to a class Contract where I make a contract about the related person:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Name"))
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Surname"))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=32, verbose_name=_(u"Address"))
```

I need that, when the button takes me to the form to create the contract, some fields're already populated with information about the person (name, surname, addres). That information is already in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the Django Model Form documentention, especially the [providing initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values) part.

From the docs :

```
class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                            help_text="Use puns liberally")
    content = models.TextField()


class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article

>>> article = Article.objects.get(pk1=)
>>> article.headline
'My headline'
>>> form = ArticleForm(initial={'headline': 'Initial headline'), instance=article)
>>> form['pub_date'].value()
'Initial headline'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass initial data for the admin form using the GET parameters.  For example:

```
/admin/app/person/add/?name=some+name&surname=surname&address=some+street
```

will open `Person` creation form with prepopulated fields.

Answer (score 0):

Django got your back. Check out [form.initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial)

`form = YourForm(intial={'name': name ...} )`

Then you can render the form manually in your template.